# Symfony 6: How to SAFELY replace deleted constant HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR (AWS ELB)?

Tags: php, symfony, proxy, symfony6, aws-elb

Having some project which is updated from Symfony 5 to Symfony 6 we have realized that a certain constant is missing.

Old code:

```
// We always trust the connecting client to be a proxy (load balancer) as we're never exposed to the internet directly
        Request::setTrustedProxies(['REMOTE_ADDR'], Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL);
```

That constant was removed for a good reason, because it is insecure in certain scenarios (e.g. if the application is directly exposed to the internet). In many cases though - like in this one - there is some load balancer having a dynamic IP (not even a fixed IP range) in front of the application (here: Amazon AWS load balancers). For me it is hard to test that properly in a staging environment, maybe someone knows already what the best replacement for AWS ELB?

My first idea was to use just all the new constants:

```
// We always trust the connecting client to be a proxy (load balancer) as we're never exposed to the internet directly
        Request::setTrustedProxies(['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR
            | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST
            | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT
            | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO
            | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB
            | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PREFIX
            | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_TRAEFIK
        );
```

Tried to do some research on the topic but I am not yet sure what the best replacement is. I am definitly sure it is not just `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR` as this caused troubles already. Also please note that `Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB` did not solve the problem in this case (not sure why).

Comment: I think this will help you. https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly

Comment: @RaviDamasiya Thanks - according to the docs: trusted_proxies: '127.0.0.1,REMOTE_ADDR' . Have  set this setting already, but still there is no proper replacement for HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ? What is it?

Comment: you can not set proxies like this in newer version of symfony please read below line I've copied from above link:   The feature to configure trusted proxies and headers with trusted_proxies and trusted_headers options was introduced in Symfony 5.2. In earlier Symfony versions you needed to use the Request::setTrustedProxies() method in the public/index.php file.